# How to return database data in HTTP get method

Tags: javascript, node.js

In server side,I fetch data from database

```
var sql = require('mssql');

app.get('/api/comments', function(request, response) {

var sqlConfig = {
// Connection string parameters.
}

  sql.connect(sqlConfig, function() {
      var request = new sql.Request();
      var stringRequest = 'select  TOP 10 * from comment';
      request.query(stringRequest, function(err, recordset) {
      if(err) console.log(err);
      sql.close(); 
      response.json(recordset);
      });
  });
});
```

Then,I fetch the data from server side by AJAX (get method)

```
 _fetchComments() {
   jQuery.ajax({
   method: 'GET',
   url: '/api/comments',
   success: (comments) => {
   this.setState({ comments })
 }
 });
```

I get an error when I get the data by Ajax.
(Uncaught TypeError: this.state.comments.map is not a function)
It seems that the data return is undefined.Instead of fetching database,the code is work if I use static data(hard code) in server side.

I think the problem is the  callback function in sql.connect() but I have no idea how to solve it.Does anyone can help?

Error:[image]

Comment: Are you using React? What is containing the _fetchComments function?

Comment: can you add the value of the **comments** variable in the success callback and also the code for the setState() function.

Comment: What is the code that generates the error?  Please show us that code.  My guess would be that you are trying to access `this.state.comments.map` BEFORE your ajax call has actually finished.  It is async and the ONLY place you know when it's done is inside the ajax callback.

Comment: Take a look in the Network tab of your dev tools and check that the response being transferred is what you think it should be.

Comment: The code that you have posted here seems to be incomplete as it doesn't contain the block which actually produces the error. Can you please edit your post to show us the complete code?

Comment: very likely that there is an error here `if(err) console.log(err);` Have you checked the logs for the error before the exception? I suspect that will provide more info.

Comment: Instead of `this.setState({comments})` try `this.setState({comments:comments.data})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is adding dataType: 'json' to the ajax

```
 _fetchComments() {
   jQuery.ajax({
   method: 'GET',
   url: '/api/comments',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: (comments) => {
   this.setState({ comments })
 }
 });
 }
```